# How to set draw distance in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have many `GLMeshItem`s in my `GLViewWidget`, which makes my plot quite slow, when I pan or zoom.

Is there any way to limit the draw distance in pyqtgraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out myself, in `GLViewWidget.projectionMatrix()` there is a local variable `farClip`:

```
def projectionMatrix(self, region=None):
    if region is None:
        region = (0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

    x0, y0, w, h = self.getViewport()
    dist = self.opts['distance']
    fov = self.opts['fov']
    nearClip = dist * 0.001
    farClip = dist * 1000.

    r = nearClip * np.tan(fov * 0.5 * np.pi / 180.)
    t = r * h / w

    left  = r * ((region[0]-x0) * (2.0/w) - 1)
    right = r * ((region[0]+region[2]-x0) * (2.0/w) - 1)
    bottom = t * ((region[1]-y0) * (2.0/h) - 1)
    top    = t * ((region[1]+region[3]-y0) * (2.0/h) - 1)

    tr = QtGui.QMatrix4x4()
    tr.frustum(left, right, bottom, top, nearClip, farClip)
    return tr
```

So the answer is to inherit from `GLViewWidget` and change `farClip`:

```
class MyView(GLViewWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def projectionMatrix(self, region=None):
        ...
        farClip = 42.
        ...
```